# AttributeError: 'Dlink' object has no attribute 'browser_driver'

Tags: python

I have created a class in python:

```
class Dlink(object):
  def __init__(self, server_ip):
    self.broswer_driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    self.base_url = "http://" + server_ip
    self.broswer_driver.implicitly_wait(30)

 def dlink_change_channel(self, channel):
    .......
    actions = ActionChains(self.browser_driver)
 actions.moveToElement(self.broswer_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href'802.11n']")).click().perform();
```

I am instantiating Dlink from another file:

```
dlink_router = dlink.Dlink(DLINK_IP)
      result = dlink_router.dlink_change_channel(channel)
```

I am trying to click on an drop down option on the webpage that is opened. I am getting below error:

> File wifi_thpt/dlink.py, line 50, in dlink_change_channel Attribute
>
> Error: 'Dlink' object has no attribute 'browser_driver'

Why I am getting this error? browser_driver is an attribute of Dlink class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your attribute is `broswer_driver` and not `browser_driver`. You have made a spelling mistake there.